# mysql 8.0 can run this sql script,but in mariaDB 5.5 can't run and error:1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE `t_test` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`runningTime` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'device running time',
  `firstLoginTime` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT (`date_format`(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %T')) comment 'device first login server time',
  `lastLoginTime` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT (`date_format`(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %T')) comment 'device last login server time',
  `lastOfflineTime` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT (`date_format`(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %T')) comment 'device last offline from server time',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

this is my create TABLE sql,and this script can run in mysql 8.0,but can't run in mariaDB 5.5
and ERROR is :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 27 in file: 'initEmgrTable_rel.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(`date_format`(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %T')),
  `lastLoginTime` varchar(255) NOT NULL D' at line 34
```

Comment: there is no error in that CREATE TABLE , maybe in the sql itself.

Comment: Don't store `DATETIME` as `VARCHAR`. That's asking for trouble.

Comment: Maybe your version of MariaDB simply does not support expressions in DEFAULT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use function or any thing other than constant in mysql prior to 10.0

see

> The default value will be used if you INSERT a row without specifying a value for that column, or if you specify DEFAULT for that column.
>
> Before MariaDB 10.2.1 you couldn't usually provide an expression or function to evaluate at insertion time. You had to provide a constant default value instead. The one exception is that you may use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default value for a TIMESTAMP column to use the current timestamp at insertion time.
> As statet in the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#default-column-option)

Save the datetime and and convert it, when you query it

**The following is only valid for mariadb since 10.2**

You have to remove the backticks around date_format

See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d0c43ed5b5fc8e7a2332a61a31bd127d

```
CREATE TABLE `t_test` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`runningTime` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'device running time',
  `firstLoginTime` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT (date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %T')) comment 'device first login server time',
  `lastLoginTime` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT (date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %T')) comment 'device last login server time',
  `lastOfflineTime` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT (date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %T')) comment 'device last offline from server time',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

Comment: and i also try 'DEFAULT ('1')' like this to set default value,but also can't work

Comment: I changed my answer  you can't do it this way,,save the datetime as such and output when you select it

Answer (score 0):

This query works:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `runningTime` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'device running time',
  `firstLoginTime` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'date_format(now(), ''%Y-%m-%d %T'')' COMMENT 'device first login server time',
  `lastLoginTime` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'date_format(now(), ''%Y-%m-%d %T'')' COMMENT 'device last login server time',
  `lastOfflineTime` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'date_format(now(), ''%Y-%m-%d %T'')' COMMENT 'device last offline from server time',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: this is not my hope result,this script will set `firstLoginTime` to a unchangeable value 'date_format(now(), ''%Y-%m-%d %T'')'

Comment: You can change it later.